# Install Popcorn-Time on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, ppa, streaming, video-streaming

Hi guys I found a guide for install PopCorn Time on my notebook via ppa but entering the first command I have this error..can someone help me? I diden't found anything on web for the error!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install popcorn-time
```

on first command I obtain

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Comment: That PPA no longer exists.

Comment: Nice. :( There are other active method?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA does not work, so I [downloaded](https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.9-Linux-64.tar.xz) the x64 `.tar.xz`. [32bit version here.](https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.9-Linux-32.tar.xz)